# setting file name for download response in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

How can i set a file name for my downloaded binary in the following node response for get request,For now it downloads the file and set its name the to the req.url string

```
.get(function (req, res) {
  var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), '');
  path.exists(filename, function (exists) {
    if (!exists) {
      res.writeHead(404, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      });
      res.write("File Not found: 404 Not Found\n");
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
      filename += '/' + category + '/' + 'undo.png';
    }

    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500, {
          "Content-Type": "binary"
        });
        res.write(err + "\n");
        res.end();
        return;
      }

      res.writeHead(200);
      res.write(file, "binary");
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
.get(function (req, res) {
  var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), '');
  path.exists(filename, function (exists) {
    if (!exists) {
      res.writeHead(404, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      });
      res.write("File Not found: 404 Not Found\n");
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
      filename += '/' + category + '/' + 'undo.png';
    }

    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500, {
          "Content-Type": "binary"
        });
        res.write(err + "\n");
        res.end();
        return;
      }

      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=" + yourFilename,
        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
        'Content-Length': file.length
      });
      res.write(file);
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: does this need any handling in the front end or just sets the file name and its not working for right now can you please ellaborate

Comment: In front end how does your download link look like?

Comment: just contain Ids, Not good url,though i have the name just want to set that in node,since it is direct download i want the file to be exactly like  i want to

Comment: did you replaced `res.writeHead(200);` with my code?

Comment: hey thanks,What if i have the type like dox png pdf and want to attach the content type ,does the content type take everything you give and append

Comment: use `node-mime` for that